# How to use RestTemplate client for GET request when response body is void in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate client in Java and Spring Boot project and when I receive a response body from the server I have this code:

```
    private RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate;
    private ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Employee>> parameterizedTypeReference;

    ....

   ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> rtGetResponse = oauth2RestTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, parameterizedTypeReference);
```

So in this case I will receive a list of employee.

Now I want to use this method but the response body from the server is `void`, and I want to use exchange method but I don't know what to use instead of parameterizedTypeReference because the response is void. So I dont have a response body, I want only to catch the exception.

Is ok to do something like that?

```
try {
    oauth2RestTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, null);
 } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
        case BAD_REQUEST:
            throw new BadRequestException(e);
        case NOT_FOUND:
            throw new NotFoundException(e);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Void` class

```
try {
    oauth2RestTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Void.class);
 } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
        case BAD_REQUEST:
            throw new BadRequestException(e);
        case NOT_FOUND:
            throw new NotFoundException(e);
        ...
    }
}
```